# How do I rotate the object in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Ok. So i have so far found a code for a snake game on python. So far the game is working but now I have started changing the BNP's from squares to circular objects and what I want to know is how to rotate the body and head at the input of lets say the arrow keys making the body parts change. I don't know if this is possible, well it is, but not in the way I want it.
Ill post the code below.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import time

left = -20
right = 20
up = 10
down = -10

size = width, height = 640, 480
block_size = 20

class Food:
    def __init__(self, screen, snake):
        self.snake = snake
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('food.bmp').convert()
        self.spawn()

    def spawn(self):
        collision = True

        while collision:
            random_x = random.randrange(0, width, block_size)
            random_y = random.randrange(0, height, block_size)

           collision = False

            for each in snake.parts:
                if each.position.x == random_x and each.position.y == random_y:
                    collision = True
                    break

        self.position = self.image.get_rect().move(random_x, random_y)

        self.blit()

    def blit(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.position)

class Part:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, direction=right):
        self.direction = direction
    self.image = pygame.image.load('part.bmp').convert()
    self.position = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y)
    self.speed = block_size

def change_direction(self, direction):
    if self.direction + direction == 0:
            return

        self.direction = direction

    def move(self):
        if self.position.x >= width - block_size and self.direction == right:
            return False

        if self.position.y >= height - block_size and self.direction == down:
            return False

        if self.position.x <= 0 and self.direction == left:
            return False

    if self.position.y <= 0 and self.direction == up:
        return False

        if self.direction == up:
            self.position = self.position.move(0, -self.speed)
        elif self.direction == down:
            self.position = self.position.move(0, self.speed)
        elif self.direction == right:
            self.position = self.position.move(self.speed, 0)
        elif self.direction == left:
            self.position = self.position.move(-self.speed, 0)

        return True

class Parthead:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, direction=right):
        self.direction = direction
        self.image = pygame.image.load('parthead.bmp').convert()
        self.position = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y)
        self.speed = block_size

    def change_direction(self, direction):
        if self.direction + direction == 0:
            return

        self.direction = direction

    def move(self):
        if self.position.x >= width - block_size and self.direction == right:
            return False

        if self.position.y >= height - block_size and self.direction == down:
            return False

        if self.position.x <= 0 and self.direction == left:
            return False

        if self.position.y <= 0 and self.direction == up:
            return False

        if self.direction == up:
            self.position = self.position.move(0, -self.speed)
        elif self.direction == down:
            self.position = self.position.move(0, self.speed)
        elif self.direction == right:
        self.position = self.position.move(self.speed, 0)
        elif self.direction == left:
            self.position = self.position.move(-self.speed, 0)

        return True

class Snake:

    def __init__(self, screen, x=0, y=0):
        self.screen = screen
        self.head = Parthead(x, y)
        self.direction = right
        self.length = 1
        self.parts = []
        self.parts.append(self.head)
        self.extend_flag = False

    def change_direction(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def move(self, food):
        new_direction = self.direction
        old_direction = None
        new_part = None

        if self.extend_flag:
            last_part = self.parts[-1]
            new_part = Part(last_part.position.x, last_part.position.y, last_part.direction)

        for each in self.parts:
            old_direction = each.direction
            each.change_direction(new_direction)

            if not each.move():
               return False

            new_direction = old_direction

        if self.extend_flag:
            self.extend(new_part)

        for each in self.parts[1:]:
            if each.position.x == self.head.position.x and each.position.y == self.head.position.y:
                return False

        if food.position.x == self.head.position.x and food.position.y == self.head.position.y:
            food.spawn()
            self.extend_flag = True



        return True



    def extend(self, part):
        self.parts.append(part)
        self.length += 1
        self.extend_flag = False

    def blit(self):
        for each in self.parts:
            self.screen.blit(each.image, each.position)


black = 0, 0, 0

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake by Jonathan Dring')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

game = True

while True:
    snake = Snake(screen)
    food = Food(screen, snake)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_RIGHT):
                    snake.change_direction(right)
                elif (event.key == K_LEFT):
                    snake.change_direction(left)
                elif (event.key == K_UP):
                    snake.change_direction(up)
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
                    snake.change_direction(down)
                elif (event.key == K_SPACE):
                    snake.extend_flag = True

        if not snake.move(food):
            game = False
            break

        screen.fill(black)
        print ("Snake - The Game")
        snake.blit()
        food.blit()
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(100)

    while not game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_SPACE):
                    game = True
                elif (event.key == K_RETURN):
                    game = True
                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()






        background = pygame.image.load('gameover.bmp').convert()
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(100)
```

If you know how to do it please reply!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here are a few things that you can do to improve your question: 1) Try to limit the scope of your question. You're currently asking to `rotate the body and head at the input of the arrow keys`. This is really a few questions: How to render a rotated image? How to keep track of the rotation? How to collect input? Concentrate on ONE of these things. Then, show ONLY the code that you think will solve this problem, and explain why it's not working. StackOverflow works best if you have a SPECIFIC problem you're stuck on, not asking for general help coding a new feature.

Comment: This question is something you could find really easily online in documentation sites

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as there is still no answer, here is how to rotate a sprite. Naturally, you can only rotate the rect of the sprite. This function, when added to a sprite, will make it rotate when you send it an angle to point in:

```
def rotate(self,angle):
    self.rect = pygame.transform.rotate(self.rect, angle)
```

This should work.